# how to make button stay in the same position?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that I want it to stay in top centered like this in smaller screen

[image]

but in smaller screen when content is wrapping it become like this :

[image]

here is my code :

Html :

```
   <div id="mobile-footer-close">
   <button id="mobile-footer-btn">
   <div class="mobile-btn-close is-rotating-back">
   <span></span>
   </div>
   </button>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
 #mobile-footer-close {
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
flex-wrap:wrap;
}

   #mobile-footer-btn {
   position:relative;
   bottom:95px;
   right: 5px;
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #959192;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-indent: 100%;
   color: transparent;
   white-space: nowrap;
   cursor: pointer;
   }
```

Comment: user media queries to adjust where it should be in different devices(screen width) related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a property in css called media query `@media`. To adjust the position of the close button you can just do this:

```
Example:

@media screen and (max-width: `max-width-of-the-device`) {
      #mobile-footer-btn {
             /*Your code*/
       }
}
```

If you enter your code in the `#mobile-footer-btn` that code will only be executed if the width of the device for example is maximum: `700px` (example). This should help your `mobile-footer-btn` change its position in mobile screens or the desired screen size you want its position to change.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above in comment, use media query for smaller screen.
To center the button within its parent set parent's position property to relative and the button's position to absolute, then add right and left properties to the button. For example:

```
.parent { position: relative;}
.button { position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 50%;}
```